# How to Change UITableviewCell Width

Tags: iphone, ios

i am new to Iphone development, i want create a tableview that contains cells of different width, like iphone contacts app when clicked on add button a tableview appears having different sections and cell are different width compared to first and second sections.
any sample code for doing this.. ?

Comment: Those are actually `UITextField`s of different widths.

Comment: [They are custom tableview cells](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/) and UITextfields.

Comment: well, thanks for replay that helps a lot.. :) @rohan-patel

Answer (score 1):

The different sections is a function of the tableview with UITableViewStyleGrouped.  The different width cells are not individual cells.  Each row is a tableviewcell. Each cell can be customized to look at any you want. So 1 tableviewcell can have 3 fields in it, like City, State, and Zipcode.

Google is your friend for the sample code.

J